# mongodb write issues

Tags: mongodb

We have 5node replicaset , in which 2 servers are in Jacksonville datacenter and 2 servers are on Atlanta datacenter and an arbiter . I had brought down the Atlanta servers , but the write operations are getting in queue as huge ., but if we bring back any of the Atlanta servers, the queue is getting settle down . The writeConcern is set to 1, still the issue persist , Please suggest on this issue .

```
PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "MongoUAT_rs",
        "date" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:11.103Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(52),
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 3,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 3,
        "votingMembersCount" : 5,
        "writableVotingMembersCount" : 4,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                        "t" : NumberLong(52)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06.088Z"),
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                        "t" : NumberLong(52)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06.088Z"),
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                        "t" : NumberLong(52)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                        "t" : NumberLong(52)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06.088Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06.088Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1634645881, 1),
        "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
                "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
                "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2021-09-15T07:19:12.893Z"),
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(52),
                "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1631690346, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(51)
                },
                "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1631690346, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(51)
                },
                "numVotesNeeded" : 3,
                "priorityAtElection" : 2,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
                "priorPrimaryMemberId" : 2,
                "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
                "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2021-09-15T07:19:13.204Z"),
                "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2021-09-15T07:19:14.073Z")
        },
        "electionParticipantMetrics" : {
                "votedForCandidate" : true,
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(51),
                "lastVoteDate" : ISODate("2021-09-15T06:56:52.839Z"),
                "electionCandidateMemberId" : 2,
                "voteReason" : "",
                "lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1631689053, 1189),
                        "t" : NumberLong(50)
                },
                "maxAppliedOpTimeInSet" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1631689053, 1189),
                        "t" : NumberLong(50)
                },
                "priorityAtElection" : 2
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "atlmongouat2:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 406229,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645423, 1125),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645421, 1919),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:10:23Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:10:21Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.794Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.857Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(7),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "atlmongouat1:27018",
                        "syncSourceId" : 1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 18,
                        "configTerm" : 52
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "atlmongouat1:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 2421252,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:09.717Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.660Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(7),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "jaxmongouat2:27018",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 18,
                        "configTerm" : 52
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "jaxmongouat1:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 4431183,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:09.568Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.720Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "jaxmongouat2:27018",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 18,
                        "configTerm" : 52
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "jaxmongouat2:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 4431190,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                                "t" : NumberLong(52)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:06Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1631690352, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-09-15T07:19:12Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 18,
                        "configTerm" : 52,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "name" : "mongoarbuat1:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 718877,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.681Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-10-19T12:18:10.453Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 18,
                        "configTerm" : 52
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"1yROW24X4mU50Deh8QQFUjHZpKc="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6963265726354292738")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1634645886, 2)
}
```

thanks

Comment: Which version of MongoDB?

Comment: You may want to include the output of the `rs.status()` in your question post.

Comment: thanks Joe, for checking . mongodb version is 4.4.4 ( community version)

Comment: What is the output of `db.adminCommand({ replSetGetConfig: 1 }).config`

Comment: Is your arbiter located in Atlanta DC? You may deploy it in a third location.

Comment: What are the write operations? For some operations (e.g. `renameCollection` the writeConcern is set to "majority" which cannot be changed.

Comment: Maybe this one: [Mitigate Performance Issues with PSA Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/mitigate-psa-performance-issues/) - well you have a 5 member replica set, however when you teardown 2 members, then you have basically the same situation.

Comment: arbiter is located in Jaxonville datacentre .

Comment: its a scheduled job, for bulk update

Comment: the write operations with w:1 , should not be affected , but it also wait for the secondary atlanta servers to come up, to complete the write operations

Comment: if any of the Atlanta secondary is up, the write operation queue comes down very fast , please help to find out what is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 4.4 has read concern majority enabled by default.  This means that each node will keep a snapshot of the most recent data confirmed to be committed to a majority of the replica set.

In a 5 node replica set, data must be written to 3 nodes to be considered majority committed.

When you have 2 nodes down, the cluster cannot commit anything to a majority of nodes, which leads to cache and memory pressure.

To prevent this, either convert the arbiter to a data-bearing node, or set [enableMajorityReadConcern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-replication.enableMajorityReadConcern) to false in the config file.

Comment: thanks Joe, it sounds good ,

Comment: anyway to check the enableMajorityReadConcern , if it is enabled or not .
also, is it possible to change this parameter dynamically ?

Comment: I think it can only be set at startup.  Run `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")` and look in the 'parsed' section.  If it is not listed, then it is enabled.